# getting specific part from line using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find specific lines in files. When I get a match using Select-String I do not want the entire line, I just want one specific part from the line (error part).

Is there a parameter I can use to do this?

For example:

If I did

```
select-string USERINTERACTION file.txt
```

and the file contained a line with:

```
MainControlInterleaf-D: 21:59:14:631: myErrorShowTracer (300) -> Info::   USERINTERACTION: <this is the error part> from type <1> occured
```

I'd like to get a result of just  instead of the entire line getting returned.

---

**EDIT:**
One more thing I forgot: if there are differences between the lines, what do i need to change in the code?

For example:

```
log-29-10-2013_00-11-52.txt:2737:MainControlInterleaf-D: 02:50:50:097: myErrorShowTracer (300) -> Info:: USERINTERACTION: <this is the error1> from type <1> occured
log-29-10-2013_00-11-52.txt:2732:MainControlInterleaf-D: 02:50:39:933: myErrorQuitTracer (350) -> Info:: USERINTERACTION <this is the error2<br> OK ... try again.<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select-String outputs a MatchInfo object, you want to use something like this:

```
Select-String 'USERINTERACTION:\s*(.*?occured)' file.txt | Foreach {$_.matches.groups[1].value}
```

Comment: try to do it, and i got this error

"Cannot index into a null array"

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you were looking for the error after the token USERINTERACTION.

Answer (score 0):

Unless file.txt is a really big file, this should work:'

```
$regex = '.+USERINTERACTION: (.+) from type <1> occured'
(get-content file.txt) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about
     Select-String -Pattern foo -Path X:\myfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return specific results, but do not provide the script with specific criteria.

Try RegEx matching (remember that you can use pipes in RegEx to form logical `OR` gates and deal with diffferent patterns that way).

[Here's a fairly decent starting point for getting into this kind of solution](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html), if you are unaccustomed to RegEx in POSH (or at all).